# Joomla Sub-Menu Won't Expand

Tags: joomla, menu

The popular items menu on [www.nfpn.org](http://www.nfpn.org/) (displayed in right side bar) has sub-menu items defined. When someone navigates to a top-level page that's represented in that menu, I'd like for the child items to be displayed. I've played with various mod_mainmenu settings for that menu (in the modules section) without success.

How would I get the appropriate sub-menu to expand?

I'm using Joomla 1.5.21.

Comment: Have you found your answer Ben or do you need some more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site had multiple menu items in different menus pointing to the same page. After removing all but one of these menu items, the sub-menu began expanding as it should have.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the module settings for the menu, is your End Level set to 0? If so that needs to be changed to 1.
[image: Parameters]

If you have it set to 1 then under Menus > youmenuname do you have those links as child links (sub links) for the menu item?

Comment: My end level is set to "2" and child links are defined.

Comment: Are you seeing the child links in the code like are they hidden by CSS? Also in the module position do you have style="xhtml", like:

`<jdoc:include type="menu" style="xhtml" />`